# Conditionally toggle class in angular 2

Tags: html, angular

I need to toggle a class "active" on  in app-component whenever a button in "app-header" component is clicked.
Here is my app-component.html,

```
<div class="off-canvas">
    <app-header><app-header>
    <app-home></app-home>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

app-header.html

```
<div>
<!--Some code-->
<button></button>
</div>
```

How can I do this using only angular since the div and button are in 2 different components????please help I am new to angular!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter).

app-header.html

```
<div>
<!--Some code-->
<button (click)="emitClick()"></button>
</div>
```

app-header.ts

```
@Output() _clickEvent:EventEmitter<any>=new EventEmitter();

constructor(){
}
ngOnInit(){
}
emitClick($event){
  this.clickEvent.emit()
}
```

app-component.html

```
<div class="off-canvas" [ngClass]="{'someClassName':active}">
    <app-header (_clickEvent)="toggleActive($event)"><app-header>
    <app-home></app-home>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

app-component.ts

```
  active:boolean=false;    
    constructor(){
    }
    ngOnInit(){
    }
   toggleActive($event){
    // Insert click event handling here
   }
```

You should declare active variable in your app-component.ts and initialized it to Boolean. Every click will cause the active to toggle between true and false.
A class named 'someClassName' will be added by the [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) whenever the 'active' variable it true.

Comment: You are missing some quotes, your current example is not valid Angular template syntax.

Comment: Is there a way to listen to this event <app-header (_clickEvent)=active=!active><app-header> in app-component.ts???

Comment: @Laoujin Sorry Iv'e added the quotes.

Comment: @Mr.Gaja Yes you can, Iv'e edit my answer and added the toggleActive() function. Hope it helps..

Comment: @Output() must be added to app-header.ts ,                                  @Output() _clickEvent:EventEmitter<any>=new EventEmitter();

Answer (score 6):

You can bind your object to the [ngClass] directive:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'active': isActive, 'disabled': isDisabled}">
```

To share data between components, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45371025/1791913

Answer (score 2):

You can create a common service and store a variable as public, example:

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService{
    foo:string;
}
```

Then use variable in the both components as a shared variable, example:

```
@Component({...})
export class FooComponent{
    constructor(private dataService:DataService){}

    foo():void{
        console.log(this.dataService.foo);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.